# How do new and delete work and where are they stored?

Tags: c++

I have a Structure defined called `Node`.

Now, I do:

```
Node* temp;
temp = new Node();
```

temp is a pointer to a Node, which itself is a complex data type.

> Question-1: Is memory allocation on heap contiguous?
>
> Question-2: Which block of memory on heap does 'temp' exactly point to? Is it the memory address of the very first data member in the struct Node?

Now, I do:

```
delete temp;
```

> Question-3: This deallocates the memory. So, does temp point to a garbage value now or does it point to NULL?

Answer (score 3):

> Question-1: Is memory allocation on heap contiguous?

Yes, you are given a contiguous block. It does not necesarily means that two consecutive allocations will give you consecutive blocks.

> Question-2: Which block of memory on heap does 'temp' exactly point to? Is it the memory address of the very first data member in the struct Node?

Not necesarily, depends on how Node is defined and what is the ABI for your platform and compiler.

> Question-3: This deallocates the memory. So, does temp point to a garbage value now or does it point to NULL?

Yes, it keeps pointing to the same address (now free, likely to be reallocated eventually) and it is up to you to set it to NULL.

---

For question-2. Let's try a little experiment:

1) plain struct

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
        int a;
};

int main() {

 A *b=new A();

 std::cout << std::hex << b << std::endl;
 std::cout << std::hex << &(b->a) << std::endl;
}
```

and the result (compiled with cygwin)

```
0x800102d0
0x800102d0
```

So in this case we're fine.

2) Inherited

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
        int a;
};

class B: public A {
public:
        int b;
};

int main() {

 B *b=new B();

 std::cout << std::hex << b << std::endl;
 std::cout << std::hex << &(b->b) << std::endl;
 std::cout << std::hex << &(b->a) << std::endl;
}
```

And the result:

```
0x800102d0
0x800102d4
0x800102d0
```

So, B* is no longer the pointer to B's first element, but the pointer to A's first element.

3) Virtual classes

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
        virtual ~A() { }
        int a;
};

class B: public A {
public:
        int b;
};

int main() {

 B *b=new B();

 std::cout << std::hex << b << std::endl;
 std::cout << std::hex << &(b->b) << std::endl;
 std::cout << std::hex << &(b->a) << std::endl;

}
```

and the result

```
0x800102d0
0x800102d8
0x800102d4
```

Now the pointer is pointing neither to the first element of A nor the first
element of B, but to a control structure.

Comment: Is it not set to NULL when we use the delete function? Do we have to do it manually?

Comment: I ask this because I implemented a linked list and I need to delete the first node and there is only one node. So, I just delete head. Now, do I have to set head = NULL again to indicate that the list is empty, or does deleting do it automatically

Comment: @TrentBoult, it is not set to 0 by delete. You can set it to 0 if you want/need. In any case it is a recommended practice.

Comment: You are extremely skilled and knowledgable. For practical reasons, @wallky is correct. But you are a genius.

Comment: @jsantader: Got it. That was what I wanted to know. Thank you so much Sir. :)

Comment: "and it is up to you to set it to NULL." / "it is a recommended practice" - I beg to differ.. specifically, if the pointer variable is about the go out of scope anyway it shouldn't be needlessly set to `nullptr` (that just clutters the code and misleadingly suggests an ongoing importance), and as recommended practices go smart pointers are where it's at (I appreciate you mean when raw pointers are being used, but mention this so Trent and other readers can consider that alternative).

Answer (score 2):

1. The object itself is allocated from contiguous memory.  If you mean where from the heap consecutive `new` allocate from:  there is no way to know.  The heap manager is free to do whatever it wants.  In the implementations I have investigated, they are peeled from the initial heap consecutively, but after some `delete` and `free` calls, the free list is searched for a suitable block under one of several algorithms include "first fit", "best fit", etc.
2. Yes, the pointer is usually to the lowest address element of the allocated class instance.  But this is not always true for derived classes, virtual objects, etc.
3. Yes, `delete` deallocates the object, but the pointer is left pointing to the space that was allocated.  It is "bad" to dereference the pointer after `delete`.  If there is any chance of testing it again, it is good practice to set the pointer to `NULL` after `delete`.

   delete temp;   temp = NULL;

Comment: Thank you my friend. You are a really awesome guy. :)

Comment: Bonus question for both of you: What would be the implications for memory management if the struct instance were **not** allocated contiguously?  Would it even be possible to implement C/C++ memory management under such conditions?

Comment: So, is the answer to the third question NULL or a garbage value? I ask this because I implemented a linked list and I need to delete the first node and there is only one node. So, I just delete head. Now, do I have to set `head = NULL` again to indicate that the list is empty, or does deleting do it automatically

Comment: @TrentBoult: The pointer is not set to NULL by `delete` (though it ought to be).  It is effectively a garbage pointer but the value of the pointer is unchanged by `delete`.  Where it points after delete could be anything (even nothing different--the deleted intact object).

Comment: @wallyk. See my answer. I included some tests. The thing is that I believe it could not be assured, as it would depend on the ABI used by the platform/compiler. In one specific case, when dealing with classes with virtual objects, the first bytes of the object memory will have a pointer to the virtual method dispatching table.

Comment: @wallyk, thanks for fixing, I'll delete my comment now. Only to note that (depending on the memory allocator), the pointer might not point to the lowest address of the allocated memory. Some memory managers will keep control structures before and after the object memory....